# Outdoor motion sensor pendent light

Tags: lighting, motion-sensor

On my front porch I have one of those ugly builder standard porch lights.  I'd like to replace it with a pendent light, but I also want it to be controlled by motion sensor.  The primary purpose of the lighting is decorative and for comfort of my guests as opposed for security.

[image]This is a flush mounted motion sensor light , but I would like a pendent light.

I figured I could get the pendent like I would like, and rig up my own motion sensor.  Any ideas for the parts that I should use for the motion sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mount the sensor(s) in a different location from the lamps, wherever gives best sensing performance. I pull 3 conductors to the first sensor or lamp, then 4 conductors between each sensor and lamp: ground, neutral, always-hot (black) and switched-hot (red).   If it's just a branch up to the lamp, always-hot can be omitted.

From there it's a fairly simple affair: sensors get wired to neutral, always-hot and switched-hot.  Lamps get wired to neutral and switched-hot.  (and grounds, of course.)

You don't want a sensor which doesn't take a neutral; these power themselves by leaking power through the light bulbs, which makes them incompatible with modern efficient lighting.  You also can't have two of them.

Also, place lights so they don't flash directly in people's faces as they walk up the normal path and hit the detection zone. They should be off to the side so the light is welcoming, not irritating.

[The sensors I use](http://amzn.to/252RqCa) play nice with one another, so there can be more than one sensor.  Any sensor supplies power to switched-hot, and all the lamps light. One of the sensors can be a switch, timer switch etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Motion sensor module]

http://www.lowes.com/pd_182164-85538-SH-5316-WH-A_0__?productId=50029168

They sell just the sensor, which can then be mounted somewhere on the wall of your porch and wired back in to the lights controls with surface mounted conduit or above the ceiling.